# Karma: There is no server listening on port 8080

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

Recently i am trying to learn unit testing.
so, i go through tutorial and installed karma by running following codes

```
npm install -g karma
npm install -g karma-cli
```

But now when i try to execute `karma run` Its giving me feedback as

```
[2014-09-04 14:52:56.275] [DEBUG] config - Loading config /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ngTest/karma.conf.js
There is no server listening on port 8080
```

**EDIT:** Karma config

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/scripts/*.js', 
      'app/scripts/**/*.js', 
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    port: 8080,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Comment: how about `karma start`...!

Comment: @Jai while doing karma start 
Error: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine)

Comment: yes that should be because karma uses jasmine framework for testing, have you created the karma conf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should take some time to read more carefully the doc before you start. It's worth it ;)

> ```
> # Install plugins that your project needs:
> $ npm install karma-jasmine karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
> ```

From [Karma documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/intro/installation.html)

then `karma start` as pointed out in comments.